# Configuration file format that recognizes comments as a part of config

Tags: c++, qt, file-format

I am trying to decide which settings format to use for my application.
The config files will be modified from within the application.
The problem is - everything I tried loses comments on file rewrite.

boost::property_tree: JSON, INFO, INI

QSettings

libconfig: YAML

Everything does not treat comments with respect and as the file is written into - they simply vanish. XML would be one option but it is barely human readable and too complex for what I need.

Is there any format/library out there that actually respects comments?

Comment: Love your question, but tell me why in 2024 there is no solution...

Answer (score 0):

I guess because it's a bit unusual for the program to change a config file in the traditional scheme of things, where the config file is read at start up and can reasonably be considered immutable - at least by the app itself.

You might consider the approach of having a config model which can be 'decorated' with comments and rendered by the program itself. That might give you the option of using the application to create a default config file from scratch if that is of interest to you.

Each time the program starts it would read the config into the internal model, changes could then be made and the decorator / renderer could write it back. You'd probably have to have a template / schema for your model in a seperate file though; otherwise you'd end up having to hard code comments etc which is quite undesirable.

Comment: >>> for the program to change a config file                But isn't that what every persistent  configuration window do?

Comment: Quite possibly, but probably not to a config file that has been hand commented. I assume that you're implying that the comments will be made by hand. Think about it: the comments could get completely out of sync with the config values if it's changed automatically - with confusing consequences. Best to allow only manual or only automatic changes.

Comment: Value of the parameter has nothing to do with parameter's purpose, I do not think anything can get out of sync when program changes the _value_.

Comment: That rather depends on the context: whether the comment describes the parameter's purpose or explains the reason for its current setting. It's only a suggestion.